# How does springboot return json containing large floating point Numbers?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I use tensorflow serving and SpringBoot,tensorflow return a A Float Array to Spring,shape is [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUXVb.png)[257][257](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUXVb.png),Spring need return Json format like

```
{"outputs":[1][257][257][1]}
```

it's so large,always 5MB.How to simplify this data efficiently?Contain 66049 numbers.

---

added

Here are 3 node:Tensorflow Serving,Spring and mobile client.

Step1:mobile post a image to Spring,and Spring give it to Tensorflow.

Step2:Tensorflow calculate the result(Float array) and transfer it to Spring,then I want Spring transfer this array to client,but this large array need 5MB.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUXVb.png)[257][257](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUXVb.png) is Python Numpy said method,mean this array is a four dimensional array,the dimensions are 1,257,257,1.
I understand how Json represents arrays correctly, but this is too long, so this is a rough description of what it looks like

---

Because Tensorflow return Json,I used Python directly to test getting the array returned by the interface,below show tensorflow response:
[image]

In my opinion, while Float is not large, 1.32059395 is a string in the Json transport, and there are a lot of "[]", so it becomes quite large

Comment: Spring uses Jackson for serialization/de-serialization under the hood. I am sorry, but your question is very vague along with the example. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: That is not valid JSON format, perhaps you should respect a valid format for JSON as this : `{
    "outputs": [1,257,257,1]
}`

Comment: So `{"outputs":[1][257][257][1]}` really means `{ "outputs": [ [ [ [ 9.9 ], ... 255 more ..., [ 9.9 ] ], ... 255 more ..., [ [ 9.9 ], ... 255 more ..., [ 9.9 ] ] ] ] }`, for a total of 66049 numbers? And what is wrong with that? Though I don't understand how that would take up 5MB, because that would require each number to have 70+ digits, on average.

Comment: yes,I test the response,this json text is 5MB,the numbers themselves are not large, but when they become json they are very large

Comment: 5 million bytes / 66049 numbers = 75.7 bytes / number. The math is telling us that you're mistaken somewhere, because a float number doesn't take up 70+ bytes, even if we do allow for 2 bytes used for comma-separators.